# How do declare " and '?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to a javascript popup that says xxx'yyy"zzz and I was curious how to do that in selenium webdriver. The following code fails to work:

```
JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String javaScript_str = "alert('xxx\'yyy\"zzz');";
javascript.executeScript(javaScript_str);
```

I am not too sure how to declare javaScript_str.

Comment: *The following code fails to work:* how?

Comment: The error is: "WebDriverException: missing ) after argument list" on the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for single quote `'` there is no need to escape in java where as in js its needed. As u gave complete string in `''`, 
java is trying to escape before js to avoid that need to have one more `\`

Try to change this to:

```
String javaScript_str = "alert('xxx\\'yyy\"zzz');";
```